# How to make constructors from two classes work together

Tags: java

**How do I make supera print "Hello" without any edit on codes in supera.

What do I do in superb?**

```
public class supera {
public supera(){
    System.out.println("hi man");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    supera as = new supera();

}

}

public class superb extends supera{


}
```

Comment: Do you mean how to make it print `hi man`? 'cause there's not `Hello` anywhere..

Comment: This question seems like homework or a test. Isn't it?

Comment: this is unclear. is it ok for "hi man" to still get printed before "Hello", or not? Also the question is asking for supera to print "Hello", but if you edit superb then it is superb and not supera that is printing "Hello".

Comment: yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: I want to do somethings in superb and make it work on supera by using constructors, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor in the "superb" class that extends "supera". In this constructor print "hello". In your main method, instantiate "superb" and not "supera".

Comment: public superb() extends supera{
  
     }

Comment: @hjEleking no it is invalid code, what you need to do, is change your main method and instantiate class `superb` not `supera`

Comment: Is your objective to print "hello" or to avoid printing "hi man" or both?